# Selectable string filter

Tags: python, string

I am trying to create a selective string filter. I want to be able to remove all characters except those which I choose to keep.

For example, if I input the string: "I only want the vowels"

It would return: "Ioaeoe"

All other characters (consonants, numbers, symbols) would be disregarded if inputted.
Please help.

Comment: Just a reminder to accept the answer that helped you the most with your problem :-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use this code:

```
input_string = "I only want the vowels"
allowed_chars = 'AEIOUaeiou'
output_string = ''.join((c for c in input_string if c in list(allowed_chars)))
```

But there are much more solutions possible, e.g using a regex defined range.

Comment: @user3152181: Fine, consider accepting my answer ;)

Answer (score 1):

For your purpose, you can do something like this using the lambda function:

```
def is_vowel(c):
    if c.lower() in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']: return True
    return False

str = 'trial string'

def filter_vowel_string(str):
    return filter(lambda c: is_vowel(c), str)

def filter_consonant_string(str):
    return filter(lambda c: not is_vowel(c), str)

print filter_vowel_string(str)
print filter_consonant_string(str)
```

You can define all the conditional functions you want to implement as a filter. In your specific case, you need to write a function that will check if a letter is a vowel or not:

```
def is_vowel(c):
    if c.lower() in ['a', 'e', 'i', 'o', 'u']: return True
    return False
```

Then, filter the string. Likewise for other filters. You can ideally pass the string through all the filters you want and get the final string.

Hope this helps.